# Prove that $13\vert(3^{n+1} +3^{n} +3^{n-1})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, divisibility

> Prove that $3^{n+1} +3^{n} +3^{n-1}$ is divisible by $13$ for all positive integral values of $n$

Comment: Did you make an attempt? What happens if you factor out $3^{n-1}$?

Comment: I'm 14..so expect me to be a little dumb.
No...I can't factor it out

Comment: $$ 3^{n+1}+3^n+3^{n-1}= 3^{n-1}\left(\frac{3^{n+1}}{3^{n-1}}+ \frac{3^{n}}{3^{n-1}}+ \frac{3^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}} \right)= 3^{n-1}\left(3^2+ 3^1+ 1 \right)= 3^{n-1}\left(9+ 3+ 1 \right)= 3^{n-1}\left(13 \right) $$

Comment: 14, and learning number theory? I doubt you're dumb!

Comment: @GFauxPas : I am not sure if some one call this as number theory... this is usual mathematics taught to normal 14 year student....

Answer (score 5):

$3^{n+1}+3^n+3^{n-1}=3^{n-1}(**+**+**)$

Can you see it now???

Answer (score 3):

Observe that
$$1\bmod13=1,\\3\bmod13=3,\\9\bmod13=9,\\27\bmod13=1,\\81\bmod13=3,\\243\bmod13=9,\\...$$
The modulos repeat periodically and the sum on a period is $13$.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the obvious factorization approach, you can reason by induction.

$$3^{(n+1)+1}+3^{(n+1)}+3^{(n+1-1)}=3\cdot 3^{n+1}+3\cdot 3^n+3\cdot 3^{n-1}=3 \cdot (3^{n+1}+3^n+3^{n-1}),$$
and
$$3^{1+1}+3^{1}+3^{1-1}=13.$$
Hence
$$S_{n+1}=3\cdot S_n\text{, and }S_1=13.$$

Comment: @flawr: if you like to fix the dots, do it consistenly. The last one is a full stop.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I just changed it because the low dot "$.$" normally indicates decimals, and confused me as a reader.

Comment: @flawr: you are right.